# How to count option values from different select options?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have searched the web for answers and find none that I needed. So to the question. I am making a submit form (user selects fields and types an input number to determine the price of an order) which have 2 different select option fields and 1 input field.

```
<input type="text" id="number" placeholder="please enter a number">
(user entered 35 for example)</input>

<select id="firstpick">
 <option value="50">Option 1</option>
 <option value="150">Option 2</option>
 <option value="100">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="secondpick">
 <option value="10">Option 4</option>
 <option value="15">Option 5</option>
 <option value="20">Option 6</option>
</select>

<input disabled="disabled" type="text">(The total sum)</input>
```

I want to count sum of values for example: firstpick.option3 + (secondpick.option4 * number.35). In other meaning: 100 + (10 * 35) = 450. And I want to get that sum in a different disabled input field, so I can save it in database and show it to the user what is the total cost of an order by fields he selected and by number he typed in.

EDIT: The working code for you (the visitor)! http://jsfiddle.net/LoLd748n/4/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The normal practice is that you show us your code that you're struggling with and we debug/amend it to fix your issue. As it stand this is a little too broad. Here are a couple of jQuery hints which will help you: http://api.jquery.com/change, http://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: *"I have searched all the web"* - I had to remove "all" because you haven't searched "all the web"; it's much bigger than you think. Try something first, edit your question with what you tried and may have failed, then we'll be glad to help and show you where you might have made errors. As it stands, the question is too broad.

Comment: btw `<input/>` isn't a valid closing tag, so you can safely remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you goal is, but this might be close. jQuery will be helpful.

```
function getSum() {
    first = $("#firstpick").val();
    second = $("#secondpick").val();
    sum = first + second
    return sum
}
```

It may be a good idea to add an event listener to your selects. This way your field will automatically update.

You do not have to have a disabled input, it could be `type="hidden"` instead. Then it will not show up on the page.

```
$("#firstpick").on("change", function() {
    sum = getSum();
    $("#my-hidden-input").val(sum);
});

$("#secondpick").on("change", function() {
    sum = getSum();
    $("#my-hidden-input").val(sum);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But it did not quite got me the answers. I have edited the post so people can understand it better. Please take a look!